# rewrite spaces and ":" sign with "-" in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

my site articles are marked by the timedate they were published for example
articles/2013-10-03 07:25:16.html is an article, the problem is that in google analytic's i get it as two different urls where some space replaced with plus and it doesn't look nice when it replaces the url spaces with %20 and ":" with %3A

my current .htaccess has the following rewrites:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z_]+)/([a-z_\-]+)$ /$1/$2.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z_]+)$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^index / [L,R=301]

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^articles/(.+)\.html$ /articles/article.php?date=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^gallery/gallery(.+)\.html$ /galleries/gallery.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /categories.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

how can i rewrite the spaces and ":" signs to a "-"
so it would look like articles/2013-10-03-07-25-16.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteRule ^([^:]*):+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R,NE]
```

This will replace every `:` with `-` recursively.